# NextJS: Get data from local storage in getInitialProps method

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I try to migrate my project to `Next.js` framework for having SSR (Server side rendering) feature. Here is my simple page:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  static getInitialProps() {
    // api getting data. Need authentication data under local storage
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.data}</div>;
  }
}
```

The problem I met is: I want my data is from `getInitialProps` first (that is the purpose of SSR). But when sending, I need a information about user for backend API. But at this function, rendering is happened on server so I cannot get data from local storage. How can you solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: store the user info in a cookie instead of web storage, so it'll be passed in the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the call to `localStorage` into a react component lifecycle method such as `componentDidMount` and then `setState()` with the result.

It's not great, but will work.

**Note that this would obviously not use SSR.**

Comment: I know doing this means we are waiting for a call from the client (which kinda kills the point of SRR), but just how expensive is it in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const USER = 'user'
const URL = 'http://www.example.com/user'

// here you can also use isServer
if (req) {
    const {data: user} = await Axios.get(URL) 
    localStorage.setItem(USER, JSON.stringify(user))
} else {
    const user = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER))
}
```